# Local gameobject variable doesn't work using switch method (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is basic, but I couldn't find the answer. I have a function which should return game object of different types. I like using switch method to describe each type stuff. The error and line it occurs on is shown in the code below:

```
GameObject getElement(string type)
{
    GameObject newGO;

    switch(type)
    {
        case "A":
           newGO= functionWhichReturnsGameObjectWithTypeA();
           break;
        case "B":
           newGO= functionWhichReturnsGameObjectWithTypeB();
           break;
    }

    return newGO; // error: Use of unassigned local variable 'newGO'
}


GameObject myGO = getElement("A");
```

Comment: What should happen when `type` is not `"A"` or `"B"`? You don't have a `default` case in your switch statement, and your `newGO` variable won't be assigned in this case.

Comment: Initialize your variable to null initially: `GameObject newGO = null;`

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for tip. Actually error message is in the code commented, but I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `newGO` a value in every execution flow, so have a default case where you either throw an exception if the `type` argument should be either `"A"` or `"B"` and `newGO` should never null, or simply set it to null if possible.

This should work:

```
GameObject newGO;

switch(type)
{
    case "A":
       newGO= functionWhichReturnsGameObjectWithTypeA();
       break;
    case "B":
       newGO= functionWhichReturnsGameObjectWithTypeB();
       break;
    default:
       throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected argument");
}
```

or:

```
default:
   return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stefan comment, this did the trick:

```
GameObject newGO = null;
```

Comment: It might get past the compiler error but might give you a runtime error if the value is not expected to be null, so keep that in mind